# unable to publish Report parts through Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I am using Report Builder 3.0. I am able to deploy reports through Report Builder. But when I tried to Publish Report parts, it's showing an error. And I am sure that I have connection to the Report Server. The error is like following,

```
Report parts failed to publish, 0 published successfully
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have permission to publish to report parts folder on the report server?

Comment: Yes, I have both System Administrator and System User rights.

Comment: Finally I got it. Express does not support to publish Report Parts. I have published them using Evaluation Edition.

Comment: It's lovely that it gives you no diagnostics at all, just Failed.  Nice work Microsoft. Still seeing this craziness in Server 2016.

Answer (score 4):

Workaround is to use the upload button on the website

http://yoursite/reports

Upload your `.rdl` file that way and skip the desktop tool's Publish feature completely.

[image]